# No value given for one or more required parameters in dapper with database MS-ACCESS in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, sql-update, dapper

if I run without dapper on button1 then there is no error and successfully update while if I run dapper on button2 then there is an error "No value given for one or more required parameters".

is there something wrong with the function method code i.e. "UpdateSacknumber". Please Guide me.

Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Private uService As New Stockservice()
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim con As OleDbConnection
        Try
            con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\dapperdemo.accdb")
            cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Stocks SET SACK_NUMBER=? WHERE CODEPRODUCT=? and BARCODE=? and COLORCODE=? and SIZE=?", con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox3.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox4.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox5.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record Updated")
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            uService.UpdateSacknumber(New Stocks() With {
    .Sack_Number = TextBox1.Text,
    .CodeProduct = TextBox2.Text,
    .Barcode = TextBox3.Text,
    .Colorcode = TextBox4.Text,
    .Size = TextBox5.Text
        })
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class Stockservice
    Private ReadOnly _conn As OleDbConnection
    Private _connectionString As String = GetOledbConnectionString()
    Public Sub New()
        _conn = New OleDbConnection(_connectionString)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetOledbConnectionString() As String
        Return "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\dapperdemo.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    End Function
    Public Sub UpdateSacknumber(ByVal Obj As Stocks)
        Dim sql = $"UPDATE `Stocks` Set `SACK_NUMBER`= {Obj.Sack_Number} WHERE `CODEPRODUCT`='{Obj.CodeProduct}' and `BARCODE`='{Obj.Barcode}' and `COLORCODE`='{Obj.Colorcode}' and `SIZE`='{Obj.Size}';"
        Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(GetOledbConnectionString())
            _conn.Execute(sql)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
Public Class Stocks
    Public Property CodeProduct() As String
    Public Property Barcode() As String
    Public Property Colorcode() As String
    Public Property Size() As String
    Public Property Qty_Stock() As Integer
    Public Property Qty_Stockin() As Integer
    Public Property Qty_Stockout() As Integer
    Public Property Sack_Number() As String
End Class
```

Error No value given for one or more required parameters

[image: Error No value given for one or more required parameters]

Comment: Just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](https://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: After that, if you comment out the Try...Catch code, it will be able to show you the complete error message, which might give you enough information to figure out which parameter is missing. (Also, it would be a Good Idea to give the controls meaningful names.)

Comment: I notice that the code has `Sack_Number() As String` but there are no quotes around `{Obj.Sack_Number}`.

Comment: Why are you using parameters in one place and not in the other? ALWAYS use parameters.

Comment: @AndrewMorton , for this link [link]( Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?) The link refers only to your profile account. Thank you for your recommended link

Comment: @AndrewMorton , `I notice that the code has Sack_Number() As String but there are no quotes around {Obj.Sack_Number}` Thank you solution from you solved my problem because of problem from quotes

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `Why are you using parameters in one place and not in the other? ALWAYS use parameters.` thanks for your reply , you mean please give guidance to your mean method in dapper

Answer (score 0):

You don't run with Dappper in Button1. You are creating a command, that's not the Dapper way of doing it. I think you should do something like the following (pardon my vb):

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As OleDbConnection
    Dim query As String
    Try
        con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\dapperdemo.accdb")
        query = "UPDATE Stocks SET SACK_NUMBER=? WHERE CODEPRODUCT=? and BARCODE=? and COLORCODE=? and SIZE=?"
        con.Open()
        Dim params As DynamicParameters = New DynamicParameters()            
        params.Add("?", TextBox1.Text)
        params.Add("?", TextBox2.Text)
        params.Add("?", TextBox3.Text)
        params.Add("?", TextBox4.Text)
        params.Add("?", TextBox5.Text)
        con.ExecuteNonQuery(query, params)
        MsgBox("Record Updated")
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

DynamicParameters is a Dapper type meant to hold parameters. It's important that you add the parameters in the order they are specified in the query. `params.Add` calls `AddWithValue` underneath, so you should also specify the type of the parameter as in the links @AndrewMorton suggests.

Comment: `You don't run with Dappper in Button1` thanks your answer but the one in button1 it is command and in button2 it is dapper. If in dapper whether it is necessary to determine the type of parameter or not.  if you don't mind your answer can it update according to the code from me which is in button2 so use the function method I created and then you can add it with DynamicParameters.